# Why HttpErrorResponse Always Get "OK" in statusText

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs

***Always Getting StatusText: "OK"***

I setup HTTPS ssl certification for testing, so why it's always getting OK in StatusText, It suppose to return "Bad Request" Or "UnAuthorized" ...etc. I need some help please to understand why is the error in statup class or in angular front-end.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FV2p.png)

**API buggy Controller**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BuggyController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext __context;
    public BuggyController(ApplicationContext _context)
    {
        __context = _context;

    }
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("auth")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetSecret()
    {
        return Ok("secret Text");
    }

    [HttpGet("not-found")]
    public ActionResult<AppUser> GetNotFound()
    {
        var userIsExsists = __context.AppUsers.Find(-1);

        if (userIsExsists == null) return NotFound();

        return Ok(userIsExsists);
    }

    [HttpGet("server-error")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetServerError()
    {
        var userIsExsists = __context.AppUsers.Find(-1);

        var response = userIsExsists.ToString();

        return response;
    }

    [HttpGet("bad-request")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetBadRequest()
    {
        return BadRequest("This Request Is a Bad Request!");
    }
}
```

**dotnet Custome Exception Middelware Class**

```
 public class ExceptionMiddelware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly ILogger<ExceptionMiddelware> logger;
        private readonly IHostEnvironment env;

        public ExceptionMiddelware(
            RequestDelegate next,
            ILogger<ExceptionMiddelware> logger,
            IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            this.next = next;
            this.logger = logger;
            this.env = env;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                context.Response.ContentType = "Application/Json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                var response = env.IsDevelopment()
                ? new ApiException(context.Response.StatusCode, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString(),
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) : new ApiException(context.Response.StatusCode, "Something Happend Wrong!");

                var jsonOption = new JsonSerializerOptions{PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase};

                var jsonResponse = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response, jsonOption);

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonResponse);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Usage Of Custom Middelware**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddelware>();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(policy =>
            policy.AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

**Interceptor Angular Class**

```
    @Injectable()
export class ErrorsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private route: Router, private toast: ToastrService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((errorResponse) => {
        if (errorResponse) {
          switch (errorResponse.status) {
            case 400:
              if (errorResponse.error.errors) {
                const modelStateErrors = [];
                for (const key in errorResponse.error.errors) {
                  if (errorResponse.error.errors[key]) {
                    modelStateErrors.push(errorResponse.error.errors[key]);
                  }
                }
                throw modelStateErrors;
              } else {
                this.toast.error(errorResponse.statusText, errorResponse.status);
              }
              break;
            case 401:
              this.toast.error(errorResponse.statusText, errorResponse.status);
              break;
            case 404:
              this.route.navigateByUrl("/not-found");
              break;
            case 500:
              const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
                state: { error: errorResponse.error },
              };
              this.route.navigateByUrl("/server-error", navigationExtras);
              break;
            default:
              this.toast.error("Something Unexpected Happened!");
              console.log(errorResponse);
          }
        }
        return throwError(errorResponse);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**Calling API**

```
    get404Error() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "buggy/not-found").subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  get400Error() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "buggy/bad-request").subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  get500Error() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "buggy/server-error").subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  get401Error() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "buggy/auth").subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  get400ValidationError() {
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "Acccount/Register", { }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23334

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue here's...., I created [local domain with free ssl certificate](https://betterprogramming.pub/trusted-self-signed-certificate-and-local-domains-for-testing-7c6e6e3f9548), just for test, which make me using **HTTPS** instead of **HTTP**, that's the issue after using http not https it works find

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhOB3.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).